# How to check if nVidia driver installed correctly Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I have installed nvidia driver on Ubuntu 18.04 as described in [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), but my laptop gets overheated sometimes.

How can I make sure drivers are installed successfully and correctly in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to open up your terminal and run the following command:

`nvidia-settings`

This will show you settings about your NVIDIA Driver as well as your X Server Information and will even allow you to change certain options like power saving mode.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt-cache policy nvidia-340
```

In the return you see the word installed.

Answer (score 0):

try `which nvidia-smi`

this will tell you where your nvidia driver is installed.